# Word Online: Line break Issue

Tags: ms-word, office-js

The last couple of days we have started seeing extra link breaks are created when the links are removed. This was working well until last few days. See below additional details

In the attached image, on the left, we don’t see extra `div`. But on the right, we see an extra `div` element. This was not present before.

Were there any updates pushed that changed this functionality?

[image]

Please let me know if you need any other information

Comment: Can you share more information about the steps of seeing the extra line breaks? which kinds of operations have you done to see the breaks? Also what do you mean "when links are removed"?

Comment: we markup cites using content controls and add hyper link into cites found in word document. We have feature in our application to remove the hyperlinks created by our application. When we remove hyperlink hyperlinks we see those extra div tag as shown in screenshot.

Comment: We still can't get enough information to reproduce this issue. Please provide a document with hyperlinks on content controls and the detailed API code to remove the hyperlinks (are you trying to remove just the hyperlinks or texts or content controls?)